# How to query a NTP server without root?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

People are saying `ntpdate` is deprecated and I should use `ntpd`. But how can I run `ntpd` to simply query a NTP server without root?

Comment: They're saying using `ntpdate` to set the clock is deprecated. As a simple query tool, it's perfectly fine.